# Write these for loops shorter

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I want to **reduce number of characters**.I want to print a special square matrix who change 5 times in c++.

How can write these for loops shorter ??
or
 How can I do same thing but shorter ??

If that is possible please help !

```
int i,j,h;

for(h=0;h<6;h++){
  for(j=0;j<13;j++){
    for(i=0;i<13;i++){
        //do something
}}}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to ask.  What do you mean  by shorter?

Comment: Looks pretty "short" to me.  What exactly is the problem here?

Comment: I want to reduce number o characters of that code . I need to write that shorter.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?  You should write clear and maintainable code.  That meas using descriptive variable names and using whitespace to break things up and make it easier to read.

Comment: You don't. What is the problem anyways.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you want to reduce number of characters, some code puzzle?

anyway, for your initial code:

```
int i, j, h;

for(h=0;h<6;h++){
    for(j=0;j<13;j++){
        for(i=0;i<13;i++){
            printf("%d %d %d\n",h,j,i);
}}}
```

here is quick version:

```
int i=0;for(;i<1014;i++)printf("%d %d %d\n",i/169,(i/13)%13,i%13);
```

replace printf with yours "something"

Comment: Do not encourage the poster? His colleagues will hate you!

Comment: @EdHeal don't kill the messenger :)